# What is the default alias name and keystore path if not provided

Tags: java, keytool

```
keytool -genkey -alias test -keyalg RSA
```

What will exactly happen if I write that command? Tell me clearly. I am a bit confused. And if keystore path is not given where it will store it?

Comment: [`keytool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) [`-genkey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html#keytool_option_genkeypair) [`-alias test`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html#CHDJHCAA) [`-keyalg RSA`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16979338/1813169)

Comment: See the [keytool option documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/keytool.html#GUID-5990A2E4-78E3-47B7-AE75-6D1826259549__CHDGIGAE).

Answer (score 1):

> What happens when you run following command,
> *"keytool -genkey -alias test -keyalg RSA"*

When you run above command, you are telling keytool utility to generate a key using RSA algorithm and give this key an alias "test" and store it in your default keystore as defined in the environment variable `HOMEPATH` or `USERPROFILE` (in case of Windows e.g. `c:\Users\[yourusername]\.keystore`)

> What is the default alias?

If you do not explicitly define an alias, it defaults to `mykey`. You sure can read the `keytool` documentation and educate yourself as mentioned by **@szogoon** but if you are short on time or do not have the motivation to do that,  you can practically find it out yourself by doing as follows:
on you terminal (in case of Windows, your command terminal environment), type as follows:

```
c:\yourpath\keytool -list -storepass yourpassword
```

Output

```
Keystore type: PKCS12

Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

**mykey**, Jan 6, 2022, PrivateKeyEntry,

Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): D6:7C:BE:E4:EF:3A:AA:61:C4:A9:ED:A9:25:36:13:AF:26:FC:3B:39:3E:6E:...*
```

In this Command line output, the text in bold in the line containing date and `PrivateKeyEntry` is your default alias.

Answer (score 0):

From the keytool documentation:

> **Option Defaults**
>
> The following examples show the defaults for various option values.
>
> -alias "mykey"
>
> -keystore {the file named .keystore in the user's home directory}